# sql + xquery to delete multiple parent nodes

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, xpath, xquery

In the below xml i have three 5 /Item elements, 4 of which have a Blob child element.  I want to delete the elements that have a child Blob element but only where Item/@Name has the text "Blob" in it.

```
<Items>
    <Item Name="Blob123">
        <Blob/>
    </Item>
    <Item Name="Blob124">
        <Blob/>
    </Item>
    <Item Name="Blob125">
        <Blob/>
    </Item>
    <Item Name="Blob126">
    </Item>
    <Item Name="Xyz126">
        <Blob/>
    </Item>
</Items>
```

This query returns the 3 /Item elements named 'Blob%' and with a child /Blob element just fine.

```
  select xmlVal.query('(/Items/Item[contains(@Name, "Blob")]/Blob/..)')
```

However when i attempt to delete those element using this xquery:

```
  select xmlVal.modify('delete (/Items/Item[contains(@Name, "Blob")]/Blob/..)')
```

I get:  Incorrect use of the XML data type method 'modify'. A non-mutator method is expected in this context.

What am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps others, to fix this i need to use update/set and also needed to change the xpath slightly

update table1
set xmlVal.modify('delete (/Items/Item[contains(@Name, "Blob")][Blob])')